# url encoding issue in iOS7

Tags: ios, encoding

I am having a link that i want to post the data.

I am using url encoding like,

`http://admin:testsite@www.arabcircleonline.com/index.php?%@=%@",form_urlencode_rfc3986(@"do"),form_urlencode_rfc3986(@"/webservice/whisper/login_chauhankevalp@gmail.com/password_keval/action_whisper/whisperdata_{\"user_status\":\"last123\",\"privacy\":0,\"privacy_comment\":0}`

This is giving the response intended when a record should be added, but the record is not getting added, when i execute this link on browser, it works fine.
Please help me out of this.. i am working on this last 2 days with no solution

form_urlencode_rfc3986 method i am using is,

```
NSString* form_urlencode_rfc3986(NSString* s) {

CFStringRef charactersToLeaveUnescaped = CFSTR(" ");

CFStringRef legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped = CFSTR("/%&=?$#+-~@<>|\\*,.()[]{}^!");
NSString *result = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(    kCFAllocatorDefault,(__bridge CFStringRef)s,charactersToLeaveUnescaped,legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped,          kCFStringEncodingUTF8));

return [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

}
```

Comment: Hello,sorry, i am not getting what you have edited in that, can you please clarify?

Comment: I've edited *my* code snippet. Your code just got a better formatting. However, it's not clear at the first glance what you are showing with the url string. Please edit it, and show what you are doing here.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to do this:

You have a url with a query. The query component is separated by a `"?"` as illustrated below:

```
URL :=   scheme-authority-path "?" query
```

In your case "scheme-authority-path" is

`http://admin:testsite@www.arabcircleonline.com/index.php`,

and a "query" is a list of parameters, separated by a `"&"`.

Your URL string without query (scheme, authority and path):

```
NSString* urlString = @"http://admin:testsite@www.arabcircleonline.com/index.php";
```

Compose a parameter (which is part of the query), e.g. in BNF

```
parameter := name "=" value
```

NOTE: *name* and *value* need to be encoded with the helper function.

which corresponds in code:

```
NSString* parameterString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",
    form_urlencode_rfc3986(@"do"),
    form_urlencode_rfc3986(            
    @"/webservice/whisper/login_chauhankevalp@gmail.com/password_keval/action_whisper/whisperdata_{\"user_status\":\"last123\",\"privacy\":0,\"privacy_comment\":0")
   ];
```

A query string is composed by concatenating (encoded) parameters and separating them by a `"&"`, e.g. in BNF:

```
query  := parameter ["&" parameter]
```

You have only one parameter, thus our query string becomes just the parameter string:

```
NSString* queryString = parameterString;
```

Now, compose the *complete* url string (including the query) from the former urlString (scheme, authority and path) and the query, by concatenating *urlString*, a `"?"` and the query. For example:

```
NSString* urlStringWithQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@", urlString, queryString];
```

Comment: this is what i am trying with, i am receiving the response string from server, but the data is not getting added, and when i execute this URL in browser it adds the data.. don't know what i am doing wrong

Comment: First, ensure you have properly composed the URL. NOTE: the parameter *value* needs to be understood by your server, since it is *special* since it has a *structure*.  Now, if the URL works in the browser, the URL seems to be valid and apparently "understood" by the server application. You need now to investigate your network code, and check for HTTP status codes and possible errors.

Comment: NOTE: (once more) fixed a typo in the string literal. Please check the code snippet again!

Comment: I am getting the response code 500, which does mean Internal server error actually in w3, how could i relate to the solution?

Comment: This means, that the URL is syntactically valid, but it does NOT imply that the *server* understands the *semantical meaning* of the *query*. Are you 100% sure the server does understand the decoded parameter key/value pair: `key = "do", value = "/webservice/whisper/..."` as shown in my code snippet?  NOTE: the parameter value could be malformed but be still a valid URL query component.

Comment: If you are performing a POST request, you should also test whether you have success when putting the query component into the body of the POST request. You can try content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and use the encoded query-string, or you can try a multipart form-data message, or you could try content type JSON and pass the parameter as JSON in the body.